# SQL - extract time and offset from it

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a DateTime field within a table.  How can I extract just the time from the row and then return an offset value.

For example, I want to offset against midnight.  So if the time is 00:45, I want the value 45.  If the time is 23:30 I want the value -30.

Thanks.

Comment: why -30?  When does your imaginary formula switch from being positive to negative?

Comment: @Fosco. Because 23:30 is 30 minutes *before* midnight. Not sure what midday would return though.

Comment: @PaulG  :)  That's my point... there isn't enough information provided to create an accurate formula without making assumptions.

Comment: 23:30 also could be 23*60 + 30 minutes 'after' midnight and 00:45 could be 23*60 + 15 minutes 'before' midnight - your requirement is ambiguous - what is your definition of midnight?

Comment: Hi,  I'm capturing scientific data, that has a legacy column within the database that was used to keep track of time points of experiments.   The method used was midnight = zero time.  the -30 refers to the measurements taken 30 minutes prior to the experiment.  The other times, eg 00:45 indicates a measurement taken 45 minutes after the experiment.  I hope i have explained this clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok..assuming time from 12 to 23 hrs as before midnight and 0 to 11 hrs as after midnight, in other words as  @Tony Andrews said **midday is treated as 720 minutes before midnight**

Here is another solution -

```
SELECT (
  CASE
    WHEN TO_CHAR(datetimefield,'HH24') BETWEEN 12 AND 23
    THEN -1 * (60 * (12 - TO_CHAR(datetimefield,'HH')) - TO_CHAR(datetimefield,'MI'))
    WHEN TO_CHAR(datetimefield,'HH24') BETWEEN 0 AND 11
    THEN 60 * (TO_CHAR(datetimefield,'HH')) + TO_CHAR(datetimefield,'MI')
  END) diff
FROM (select systimestamp datetimefield from dual);
```

I used my systemtimestamp for testing, You need to replace the the query `select systimestamp datetimefield from dual` to fetch your own datetime field from your table to make it work for you.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
(datecol - round(datecol))*24*60
```

For example:

```
with times as
( select trunc(sysdate) t from dual
  union
  select trunc(sysdate)+0.25 t from dual
  union
  select trunc(sysdate)+0.5 t from dual
  union
  select trunc(sysdate)+0.75 t from dual
)
select (t-round(t))*24*60 from times;

0
360
-720
-360
```

Note that midday is treated as 720 minutes **before** midnight.

Answer (score 0):

A list of Oracle-supported datetime formats can be found here: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

You can use these formats with the to_char function - for example:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'mi') from dual
```

You seem to have picked a way of representing times that isn't among those supported, but Tony's answer should meet your requirements.